# Implement AD and Group policies over VPN

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, vpn, group-policy, sophos

We have multiple sites with each site having 5 to 10 systems.

All sites are connected to HQ through VPN configured on firewall. (Each site has their own firewall)

What I want is to connect remote location systems to AD and impose group policies on them. what steps should I follow?

Comment: Join the systems to the domain. If they're already joined to the domain then you shouldn't need to do anything.